# Set starting point for breaks for labels in ggplot using geom_bar [R]

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am making a time series using bars in ggplot. When I set the breaks to 2 months (to make it a bit more legible than using 1 month, but more useful than using 1 year), it starts counting from the second month. I've noticed that the same thing happens if I set a different number - if I set 3, the labels start in March, etc.

This doesn't happen if I do a line graph - then the breaks start at the first month, but still have the 2 monthly breaks.

How can I make the labels start on the first month and then set the breaks from there? I would also be happy with them counting backwards from the last month.

Here is my code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)

num_month <- seq(from = as.Date("2016-01-01"), to = Sys.Date(), by='month')
month_data <- as.data.frame(matrix(0, ncol = 0, nrow = length(num_month)))
month_data$month <- as.Date(num_month)
month_data$month_char <- format(month_data$month,"%Y-%m")
month_data$freq <- sample(100, size = nrow(month_data), replace = TRUE)
month_data <- month_data[!(month_data$month_char %in% current_month),]
random_bar_ts <- ggplot(month_data, aes(x = month, y = freq)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5, size = 12)) +
    scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%b-%y"), breaks = "2 months", expand = c(0,0))
random_bar_ts

random_line_ts <- ggplot(month_data, aes(x = month, y = freq)) + 
    geom_line() + 
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5, size = 12)) +
    scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%b-%y"), breaks = "2 months", expand = c(0,0))
random_line_ts
```

Here is what the two plots look like: 
[image: geom_bar example]

[image: geom_line example]

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is indeed unintuitive and it looks like there are no parameters to somehow directly shift the labels. What you can do, though, is to really easily set those breaks manually, especially since in this case your data is nicely sorted:

```
ggplot(month_data, aes(x = month, y = freq)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5, size = 12)) +
  scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%b-%y"), expand = c(0, 0),
               breaks = month_data$month[c(TRUE, FALSE)])
```

[image]

Even if you had somehow irregular data, you could easily set the breaks (which seems to be the same or almost the same what `scale_x_date` does too) with 2 month intervals as in

```
with(month_data, seq(min(month), max(month), by = "2 months"))
#  [1] "2016-01-01" "2016-03-01" "2016-05-01" "2016-07-01" "2016-09-01" "2016-11-01" "2017-01-01"
#  [8] "2017-03-01" "2017-05-01" "2017-07-01" "2017-09-01" "2017-11-01" "2018-01-01" "2018-03-01"
# [15] "2018-05-01" "2018-07-01" "2018-09-01" "2018-11-01"
```

Comment: Thank you, great to have options!